# How can i initialize a custom interface

Tags: java, android, interface

I have an interface:

```
public interface ToggleChartListener {
    public void onToggleChartChanged(boolean isPie);
}
```

I want to call it from activity A, so that activity B can listen to the change.

This is what I've tried so far, but I'm getting an ClassCastException:

```
ToggleChartListener toggleChartListener = ((ToggleChartListener)getApplicationContext());
toggleChartListener.onToggleChartChanged(true);
```

How can I initialize the interface?

Comment: I'd recommend going back to basics by reading ["What is an interface?"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Interfaces are **not** classes, and therefore cannot be instantiated. Instead, interfaces are a set of common method declarations that classes can choose to implement.

Comment: use handler to pass message between activity instead of interface.

Comment: In your instance, `Context` does **not** implement `ToggleChartListener` and therefore cannot be cast to `ToggleChartListener`.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya, I don't agree, using handler is not a recommended approach,it usually leads to IllegalArgumentException(there where we have to protect it using isAdded() or isFinishing()) & many other issues related to Bundle however interface in recommended.

Comment: @Astha, It does not create an issue if we initialize handler in `oncreate` and assign null in `finish` and `destroy`.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya, yes, it won't give IllegalArgumentException but there's still size constraint in passing data in Bundle using Handler.

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221687/7783718) and I am using it in all old apps.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya, Handler doesn't create any problem for smaller data transferred in Bundle but it will start giving you TransactionTooLarge if Bundle size passed using handler exceeds 1MB. It's tried & tested problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing due to `((ToggleChartListener)getApplicationContext());`. You need to typecast the instance of `Activity B` to `ToggleChartListener` to further call `onToggleChartChanged()` from `Activity A`.

Also, why do you want your Activity B to listen to the changes? As 2 activities can't be visible to a user at the same time? (Instead you can use `startActivityForResult()`)

Answer (score 0):

It is not right way to communicate with different activity via interface. 
So you can follow the below way.
You have an Interface `ToggleChartListener`. In your Activity A you have to declare interface object like: `private ToggleChartListener listener;` and then you have to create a method something like that:

```
// static because A is an activity you may not b access method from other activity
public static void initCallback(ToggleChartListener listener){
  this.listener = listener
}
```

Now you can call your interface method:

```
listener.onToggleChartChanged(true);
```

In Activity B you have to call:

```
ActivityA.initCallback(new ToggleChartListener()) // here you get override method onToggleChartChanged to access data
```

**N.B:** But the easy way to pass value from Activity A to Activity B is `Intent`
If the situation is you are in Activity A the you are going to Activity B after return Activity A you need the result then you can use `onActivityResult` Method by calling `startActivityResult` method from your Activity A